# Converting a java long unix timestamp for use in mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, unix

Does anyone know how I could convert a unix timestamp in the long data type into a unable format within a mysql database?  When I try and enter the timestamp as an integer the value comes up as a negative in the database.  (not quite sure why since a 32 bit signed int should be able to handle this)

Comment: The java timestamp is in millis, so if you divide by 1000 you should be fine for another 24 years.

Comment: can you show your code snippets?

Comment: Date now = new Date(); int timestamp = (int)now.getTime();

Comment: Kevin set that as an answer and I'll set that as accepted, thanks!

Comment: Yes, yes, keep creating Y2038 bugs for us to fix at absurd consulting rates right before retiring!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can get it like so:

```
long unixTime = Date.getTime()/1000;
```

Comment: Which you can then cast to an `int` (assuming you don't need any dates past 2038).